# PHP | What are three dots before a function arguments?

Tags: php, laravel

I was working with Laravel 5.3 and in one of the functions, I found this piece of
code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $this->authenticate($guards);

    return $next($request);
}
```

The code comes from `\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class`.

What are those 3 dots before `$guards` variable?

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking - if you're ever unsure, there's a comprehensive list of symbols in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-do-various-symbols-mean-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It indicates that there may be a variable number of arguments.

When the function is called with more than 3 arguments, all the arguments after `$next` will be added to the `$guards` array.

You can read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list).

Comment: Will `$guards` still be an array if a ONLY 3 parameters are sent?

Comment: Just noticed the last time the answerer was available (Dec 11 '16 at 19:52), if anyone else stumbling across can answer my above comment, please do so.

Comment: Confirmed, `$guards` will still be an array, please click [here](https://repl.it/repls/LightgreenThornyWorkspaces) to see an example.